# Real Time Graph is inconsistent in GraphView Library Android

Tags: android, graph, out-of-memory, real-time, android-graphview

I am using GraphView Library. I am plotting real time graph through some third party device via bluetooth.

It sends continnously 50 samples per sec .
I need to plot it continuously.

However i need to display around 360 samples on a screen regardless of any screen size .

for that my code is as follows:

```
    class MyHandler extends Handler {

          private final WeakReference<HomeScreenActivity> mActivity;

            private MyHandler(HomeScreenActivity activity) {
                mActivity = new WeakReference<HomeScreenActivity>(activity);
            }

            /**
             * Method handleMessage.
             *
             * @param msg android.os.Message
             */
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                final HomeScreenActivity parent = mActivity.get();
                Logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "HomeScreenActivity", "msg.what=" + msg.what);



                if (msg.what == Constants.PLETHY_1000) {
                        String str = (String) msg.obj;

                    final String[] arr = str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");

                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        mSeries2.appendData(new DataPoint(graph2LastXValue, Double.parseDouble(arr[i])), true,360);// change 360 to 40 and works fine  
                     graph2LastXValue++;

                    }
}
}
```

It works fine for some android devices 
but my application crashes after running say 2 min or 3 min on other devices.

i ll be getting error in my logcat:

```
06-13 10:30:42.012 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1554>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
06-13 10:30:42.012 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1500>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
06-13 10:30:42.022 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1554>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
06-13 10:30:42.022 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1500>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
06-13 10:30:42.022 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1554>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
06-13 10:30:42.022 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1500>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
06-13 10:30:42.022 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1554>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
06-13 10:30:42.022 31412-31452/bpl.com.bpl.com.bploximeterdemo E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1500>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
```

I came to realise that it's a memory error.

Note : As i lower the limit of my maxdata points , higher the time it will diaplay on screen.

for eg. if i change max data points 360 t0 40 it will run for more time say 25 mins.

The devices on which it is tested:

```
Motorola 3rd gen(2gb RAM,Marshmallow)- works like a charm
Mi4i -(2GB RAM,Lollipop)- crashes after some time , error shown as above
Karbonn Titanium(1 GB RAm,Lollipop)-crashes after few secs ,error shown as above
```

I don't know why it is happening .Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information to be sure about this. Is there a stack trace available? Can you tell if the crash is happening after roughly the same amount of data has been received? The easiest way to test if this is the case would be to slow the rate of data going to the app or intermittently interrupt the transfer of data. If slowing/interrupting the data does not reduce/remove the crashes, it is probably a memory leak so I'd suggest trying Leak Canary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

If slowing/disrupting the rate of data transfer does remove (or massively reduce) the crashes, I'm guessing the OutOfMemory is caused by your data getting added faster than garbage collection can free the memory used by unused data.

The append data operation in the GraphView library looks like this:

```
public void appendData(E dataPoint, boolean scrollToEnd, int maxDataPoints) {
    checkValueOrder(dataPoint);

    if (!mData.isEmpty() && dataPoint.getX() < mData.get(mData.size()-1).getX()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC.");
    }
    synchronized (mData) {
        int curDataCount = mData.size();
        if (curDataCount < maxDataPoints) {
            // enough space
            mData.add(dataPoint);
        } else {
            // we have to trim one data
            mData.remove(0);
            mData.add(dataPoint);
        }
    }

    // recalc the labels when it was the first data
    boolean keepLabels = mData.size() != 1;

    // update linked graph views
    // update graphview
    for (GraphView gv : mGraphViews) {
        gv.onDataChanged(keepLabels, scrollToEnd);
        if (scrollToEnd) {
            gv.getViewport().scrollToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

It is using `.remove()` on an ArrayList, which is not a very efficient operation. If you import the library source code to Android Studio and add your local copy to your project, replacing the ArrayList with a LinkedList (or possibly a more appropriate concurrent collection) may fix the problem.

```
final private List<E> mData = new ArrayList<E>();
```

to:

```
final private List<E> mData = new LinkedList<E>();
```

in https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/BaseSeries.java

If this did fix it, it would be worth reporting it to the library's maintainer.

Another alternative would be to throttle the rate of data transfer. For example by using RxJava: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Comment: it crashes only on certain devices , it will crash exact after 1 minute i.e plot 300 samples . At first i thought it was garbage collection issue ,but it doesn't give me memory error. It doesn't give me any stack trace

Comment: Leak Canary or Facebook's Infer are designed to catch memory leaks. They may be worth trying.